# Heroku Rails NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

My app run perfectly locally, but it encountered some trouble on `Heroku`.

**heroku logs**

```
2016-07-05T16:29:58.946783+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/posts/new" for 110.30.34.50 at 2016-07-05 16:29:58 +0000
2016-07-05T16:29:58.955329+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (2.4ms)
2016-07-05T16:29:58.955545+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
2016-07-05T16:30:05.508001+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/posts" for 110.30.34.50 at 2016-07-05 16:30:05 +0000
2016-07-05T16:30:05.510085+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0DzbuSXUyjZ4FRYietP3QSdmjfHymWyu7INcGpm79b2PgR+3LD99TS6gkYCF0FCLLHso9U7YqMh1tzr48ch8Jw==", "post"=>{"title"=>"123", "content"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
2016-07-05T16:30:05.515017+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:32:in `create'
2016-07-05T16:30:05.512757+00:00 app[web.1]:   Author Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "authors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-07-05T16:30:05.513954+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
2016-07-05T16:30:05.515003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-05T16:30:05.515016+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `author_id=' for #<Post:0x007fcf1cc579f0>):
2016-07-05T16:30:05.509973+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
2016-07-05T16:30:05.515018+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-05T16:30:05.515019+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I want to create a `post` and gave the `author_id` = `current_author.id`.

```
#in post controller

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.author_id = current_author.id if current_author
    ...
```

I've put this project on [Github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/Myblog/commits?author=fifiteen82726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed the possible solution. to make sure though,

run `heroku run rake db:version` and see if it matches your latest migration version in `db/migrate/*`

If it doesnt run `heroku run rake db:migrate` as oreoluwa and lolosco have said already.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot this simple step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you recently added the author reference to the posts table. To fix the error, I'd say you should try to do `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

migrate db on heroku

heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: Thank, it's a simple but important step.